# Load XML element by element, to save memory in PHP

Tags: php, xml, memory

I need to read an XML file on a low memory system (don't have access to increase it).
I've tried:

```
$xmlString = file_get_contents($file);
$doc= new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($xmlString);
```

and

```
$doc= new DOMDocument();
$doc->load($file);
```

Both give me memory errors.

Was wondering if there is a way to read the XML sequentially node by node, so only 1 node is in memory at any given time. I don't care how long this takes as it's a nightly batch process.

The structure of the XML is very simple:

```
        <InventoryItem>
        <SKU>125244</SKU>
        <Quantity>137196</Quantity>
        <Status>Active</Status>
        </InventoryItem>
```

repeated may times.

Maybe treating it as text?

Much thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a pull parser like [XMLReader](http://php.net/xmlreader).

Comment: This did the trick, and implementing it took 5 minutes using this example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835177/how-to-use-xmlreader-in-php Muchas Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

You want to use [SAX parsing](http://www.joemarini.com/tutorials/tutorialpages/listoflinks.php) (using the [PHP functions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php), or XMLReader, as mentioned in another answer).