# PHP XMLReader problem with htmlentities

Tags: php, xmlreader, html-entities

I am processing an external xml document using the method described here ( [How to use XMLReader in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835177/how-to-use-xmlreader-in-php/1835324#1835324) ), but I'm coming across this error:

> ...parser error : Entity 'Atilde' not defined in...

and similar, such as

> cent, acirc, not

The error occurs on the $z->expand() function. If I comment that out, it occurs on the $z->next() function.

I know the problem field and have tried to edit it with base64_encode before expanding, but it's readonly.

EDIT: the problem string is:

```
...&Atilde;&cent;&acirc;&not;&Acirc;...
```

end edit

Thank you for any help given.

Comment: you know the error are caused by HTML entities, then you should no user the XML parser. Try the DOMDocument instead (like the question you have included)

Comment: It's a large xml document, so I can't have all the memory used up

Answer (score 2):

[XML does only know the entities *lt*, *gt*, *amp*, *apos*, and *quot*.](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-predefined-ent) So any other [entity reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-EntityRef) will raise an error. (Note that [character references](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-CharRef) and entity references are not the same.)

You can use [`strtr`](http://php.net/strtr) to convert any HTML entity reference that is not also known in XML:

```
$trans = array_map('utf8_encode', array_flip(array_diff(get_html_translation_table(HTML_ENTITIES), get_html_translation_table(HTML_SPECIALCHARS))));
$output = strtr($input, $trans);
```

[`get_html_translation_table`](http://php.net/get_html_translation_table) returns an array for the mapping of character onto entity reference. `get_html_translation_table(HTML_ENTITIES)` returns a mapping for all entities while `get_html_translation_table(HTML_SPECIALCHARS)` returns only those mentioned above. [`array_diff`](http://php.net/array_diff) will give the difference, so all entities without those mentioned above. `array_flip` inverts the key/value association and applying [`array_map`](http://php.net/array_map) with [`utf8_encode`](http://php.net/utf8_encode) will convert the values from ISO 8859-1 to UTF-8.

Comment: What should I use as the input please? I tried it with $z->expand() as the input and got the error:

"Catchable fatal error: Object of class DOMElement could not be converted to string in..."

Comment: Oh, wait a second. Does setting `$z->setProperty(XMLReader::SUBST_ENTITIES, true);` before `$z->open(…)` work?

Comment: It came up with an "undefined" error, but I found setParserProperty, which I guess you meant. Unfortunately it didn't work. Thank you anyway, I appreciate your time and effort. I guess I could always tell the xml feed supplier to fix it, but they'll just ignore me.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe xml_set_external_entity_ref_handler is the solution for your case:

http://php.net/manual/en/example.xml-external-entity.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.xml-set-external-entity-ref-handler.php

Comment: I can't get it to work with XMLReader. Do you have an example.

Answer (score 0):

Encountered the same problem..

My solution was opening the XML file in notepad++, search and replaced the characters to readable ones.

Not a beautiful solution but it works;)

Answer (score 0):

This is a flaw in the original XML but it's not uncommon. I didn't have much luck with the solutions here (other than Wout van der Vegt's), so here's the "make a new XML that is fixed" approach:

```
// Needs PHP 5.4.0+

$file = "xmldata_with_entities.xml";
$file2 = "xmldata_converted.xml";

$handle1 = fopen($file, "r");
$handle2 = fopen($file2, "w");
if ($handle1) {
    while (($line = fgets($handle1)) !== false) {
        fwrite($handle2, html_entity_decode($line,ENT_HTML5));
    }
}
fclose($handle1);
fclose($handle2);
```

Obviously you could then use $file2 in XMLReader.