# How to enable XMLReader in PHP without reconfiguring PHP?

Tags: php, xmlreader, xmlwriter

My PHP info has this:

```
Configure Command : '--with-libxml-dir=/usr' 
                    '--enable-xml' 
                    '--disable-xmlreader' 
                    '--disable-xmlwriter'
```

i.e. my `xmlwriter` & `xmlreader` have not been enabled during installation.

> ```
>                                libxml
> ```
>
> libXML support                       active
>   libXML Compiled Version        2.7.8
>   libXML Loaded Version           20708
>   libXML streams                       enabled

from [php.net manual for XMLReader](http://www.php.net/manual/en/xmlreader.configuration.php)

> ## Runtime Configuration
>
> This extension has no configuration directives defined in *php.ini*.

How do I enable XMLReader? / Do I have have to compile my PHP again with --enable-xmlreader?

Comment: i'm wondering how did you install the php-xml package?

Comment: Using yum.
yum install php-xml.x86_64 
Found it in a repository.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a workaround:

First Install the package `php-xml` for my system: `php-xml.x86_64`

> Package description:
>   php-xml.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications which use XML

Install the above mentioned package(respective to your system) to enable XMLReader, XMLWriter.

```
php -i
```

has this now:

```
'--with-libxml-dir=/usr' 
'--enable-xml' 
'--enable-xmlreader=shared' 
'--enable-xmlwriter=shared'
```

I have also tested whether the package is enabled by creating an object of XMLReader.
But, I think I will be going with SimpleXML because I have to read very small xml files & because of its lower memory consumption. Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1835324/858515).

Answer (score 1):

> The XMLReader extension is available in PECL as of PHP 5.0.0 and is included and enabled as of PHP 5.1.0 by default. It can be enabled by adding the argument --enable-xmlreader (or --with-xmlreader before 5.1.0) to the configure line.
>
> This extension is enabled by default. **It may be disabled by using the following option at compile time: --disable-xmlreader**

http://www.php.net/manual/en/xmlreader.installation.php

So, compile PHP again by remove the `--disable-xmlreader`

Comment: Had read that. Is there a work around instead of compiling the whole thing again?

Comment: i dun think there is ... you should ask the one who disable this option (itchy hand, i guess)

Comment: There should be a way to do it runtime. o.0

Comment: i dun think there is, if so, PHP won't have an explicit option `--disable-xmlreader`. Just my opinion

Comment: @Consciousness I couldn't find anything official to enable it during runtime. So thought I might find a workaround here.
and Since its a PHP core feature, PECL extension has been discontinued now link: http://pecl.php.net/package/xmlReader

Comment: @NithinAG - Do you really have to use XML reader? Or you can consider simplexml, domdocument

Comment: @ajreal ya I am considedering simpleXML now.

Comment: @ajreal found a workaround please check the question for edit

Comment: @Consciousness found a workaround please check the question for edit