# Debian 9: the php5 packages is not installed

Tags: php, linux, debian

I need to install some packages to prepare the workspace for a project in the Debian 9 OS runs in a VB. I have the instruction:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
The following Debian 8 packages are required to run [X-Product]:

sudo apt-get install exim4 ntp pwgen curl php5-dev php-pear pkg-config nmap libzmq3 libzmq3-dev libapache2-mod-php5 apache2 percona-server-server-5.6 php5-cli php5-mysql php5-curl php5-intl daemontools-run oracle-java8-installer ant ruby-compass libtool-bin
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

When I run the command, I get the following terminal stack,

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package php5-cli is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

Package php5-mysql is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

Package php5-curl is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

Package libapache2-mod-php5 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Unable to locate package php5-dev
E: Unable to locate package libzmq3
E: Package 'libapache2-mod-php5' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'php5-cli' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'php5-mysql' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'php5-curl' has no installation candidate
E: Unable to locate package php5-intl
```

I did some research on the internet, did the following at next,

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
```

It doesn't help me at all. What do I need to fix this? I have very little knowledge about Debian if you ask

Note: I followed the instructions in the answer provided, the issue is still not solved like I cant see the `php version`

When I run the command of 
`sudo apt-get install php5.6`

It prints in the terminal,

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'php5.6-json' for regex 'php5.6'
Note, selecting 'php5.6-common' for regex 'php5.6'
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

To look for the `PHP` version,

```
sudo php -v
```

It prints in the terminal,

```
sudo: php: command not found
```

More info like if I run it

`sudo apt-get install php5-dev
I get error
E: Unable to locate package php5-dev`

But, the command 
`sudo apt-get install php-dev` is successful

The command 
`dpkg -l | grep php| awk '{print $2}' |tr "\n" " "` returns value,

Is that mean I hvae php7 installed and that blocks other operations?

```
dh-php php-cli php-common php-dev php-gd php-pear php-xml php7.0-cli php7.0-common php7.0-dev php7.0-gd php7.0-json php7.0-opcache php7.0-readline php7.0-xml pkg-php-tools
```

Comment: No, I have still issues

Comment: I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46378017/install-php5-6-in-debian-9) post useful to install 5.6 version of PHP on debian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package [`libapache2-mod-php5.6`](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=libapache2-mod-php5), [`php5-dev`](https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=php5-dev), [`php5-mysql`](https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=php5-mysql),[`php5-curl`](https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=php5-curl) can be installed only on debian Wheezy (7) , Jessie (8) or Sid . Also the ondrej/php repository does not provide those package for debian **Stretch**  it is only provide the `php5.6` package.

The command `sudo apt-get install php-dev` will install the [development module for PHP7](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/php-dev) :

```
dh-php libssl-dev libssl-doc php7.1-cli php7.1-common php7.1-dev php7.1-json 
php7.1-opcache php7.1-readline pkg-php-tools shtool xml2
```

Comment: The Very helpful answer maybe the right thing to do is install Jessie (8) considering my situation.

Comment: As an update, we had a complex crypto trading engine that runs only in Debian Jessie.  The situation might be different for the other people.

Answer (score 4):

Open the terminal and run the following command:

`apt-get install apt-transport-https lsb-release ca-certificates`

Get the gpg key:

`wget -O /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/php.gpg https://packages.sury.org/php/apt.gpg`

Add the new repository to your sources:

`echo "deb https://packages.sury.org/php/ $(lsb_release -sc) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php.list`

Install PHP5.6

`apt-get update
apt-get install php5.6`

**Update**

Workaround for line `echo "deb https://packages.sury.org/php/ $(lsb_release -sc) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php.list`:

Run this, and take note of the output:

`lsb_release -sc`

Open up `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/php.list` in your editor of choice and append this to the bottom:

`deb https://packages.sury.org/php/ OUTPUT_FROM_LSC_COMMAND main`

Comment: The `echo` command returns an error, `bash: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php.list: Permission denied`. I have tried with `sudo su -c echo "deb https://packages.sury.org/php/ $(lsb_release -sc) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php.list` after reading another post, this doesn't also help me

Comment: Lastly, I have tried with the command `echo "deb https://packages.sury.org/php/ $(lsb_release -sc) main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php.list` from another post and goes till to install `sudo apt-get install php5.6`. This doesnt help, same erros still

Comment: I've updated my answer, give the updated section a try.

Comment: Adam, The debian name find is `stretch` and I follow all you wrote (last 2 command with sudo). Then I execute the original instruction, and still the same error.

Comment: This solution is good for me with debian 9 but the php5.6 version there's on the sury distribution is not complete. It misses something essential like pdo or xmlreader. At least they've not been installed for me. Where can i find those packages? thanks

Comment: @TizianoMischi I think this might be a good start: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8464784/how-to-enable-xmlreader-in-php-without-reconfiguring-php

Answer (score 3):

Debian 9 does not contain PHP 5.x (see https://wiki.debian.org/PHP). To install it from the ppa, install the package `php5.6` and accordingly named other packages  (like `libapache2-mod-php5.6` instead of `libapache2-mod-php5`)

Comment: What is the error? Which line do you finally execute to install the packages?

Comment: I followed the other answer, also updated the question

Comment: Could you try `sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5.6 php5.6-cli`?

Comment: Probably, and this might install php7 as this is the default for Debian Stretch. Can you look in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ to find the file containing the repository information for packages.sury.org? Or post the output of `apt-cache policy`?

Answer (score -2):

I had this same problem, attempting to follow the instructions on php's website.

Turns out, on Debian 9, it was quite simple: just drop the version from the package names.

```
# apt-get install php-common libapache2-mod-php php-cli

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libapache2-mod-php7.0 php7.0-cli php7.0-common php7.0-json php7.0-opcache
  php7.0-readline
Suggested packages:
  php-pear
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libapache2-mod-php libapache2-mod-php7.0 php-cli php-common php7.0-cli
  php7.0-common php7.0-json php7.0-opcache php7.0-readline
```

Comment: that installed php7, op asked about php5

Comment: IIRC, I was pointing out that PHP's documentation on installation does not account for special considerations around specific distros. If one is trying to get PHP installed on a newer distro, and just following the instructions on PHP's site, this information may be useful. I'm not even sure OP requires version 5.6 actually. But I hope this may help some poor soul in the future (Unless they have updated their docs by now...??)