# PHP - Append and update large XML files

Tags: php, xml, xmlreader, google-ads-api, xmlwriter

I'm looking into the possibility of efficiently comparing two similar XML-files and updating outdated information.

The main XML-file I'm working with is about 200-250mb in size. The second is a tad smaller.

The two XML-files pretty much looks like this:

```
  <product>
   <Category>BOOK</Category>
   <Bookgroup>BOOKF</Bookgroup>
   <Productname>Name of the book</Productname>
   <Productcode>123456789</Productcode>
   <Price>79.00</Price>
   <Availability>Stock On Order</Availability>
   <ProductURL>www.url.com</ProductURL>
   <Release>07.08.2013</Release>
   <Author>Name of author</Author>
   <Genre>Crime</Genre>
   <BookType>Pocket</BookType>
   <Language>English</Language>
  </product>
```

As you can see I'm working with books, and the purpose of having a second XML-file with the same information is that I only want one copy of each book for further use.

Basically I'm trying to figure out how I effectively can parse through the first XML and check whether the book exists in the second XML. If it exists I'll check if productinformation *(price, availabilty etc)* have been updated. If this information has been updated this needs to be updated in the second XML as well.
If it doesnt exist it needs to be added to the second XML.

Using XMLReader I'm able to parse through each book from the first XML fairly fast *(40ish seconds to loop through 4,5million lines of XML and echo out all the books)* by using a similar [approach as this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1835324/2960364).

My problem occurs when I want to check if this book exists in the second XML and make changes in the second XML if it needs to be updated or added.

Would it for example be possible to use XMLReader on the second XML and stop at nodes with the same booktitle as I've stopped at in the first XML and then make the check? If so how?

Comment: I don't suppose you're lucky enough that the two book "lists" are/can be sorted the same way? (By `Productcode` - assuming that's unique to each book - would be nice!)

Comment: Does it have to be `xmlreader`?