# Loop from specific offer in XML file

Tags: php, xml

Is there a way to loop through an XML file from a specific element / node.

For instance if I want to start from `<offer id="a2a9d7a3a520de69e8e06f3e53df1c49">` in this XML feed: http://pastebin.com/n5myzcz1

Is is then possible to load all offers after that ID?

Comment: So load all offers and check id.

Comment: Problems is, that the file is around 1GB, so I need to break it up on pieces

Comment: In short, yes and yes

Comment: @RamRaider Do you have any type of tutorials on this or something that can lead me in the right direction?

Comment: use `XMLReader` from PHP, use NOT `simplexml_load_file()` it uses to much memory on a 1GB file

Comment: I'm already using that, the script is fine, I just need to find a solution to start from a specific element and loop from there

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835177/how-to-use-xmlreader-in-php

Answer (score 0):

I was going to suggest [XPath](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) but since you mention that the file is 1GB, you should use a streaming parser such as [XMLReader](http://php.net/manual/en/class.xmlreader.php) (which I now read that you are already using).

You are bound to have a linear search because you don't know where the element you want is so you have to go through all of them until you find it.

**EDIT**

Just an esoteric idea could be using `shell_exec` to `grep` the file to find the line where the ID is and then cutting the file from that line using `sed` or equivalent.

**EDIT 2**

Ahhhh, this was fun!!

```
$line = intval(shell_exec('grep -n a2a9d7a3a520de69e8e06f3e53df1c49 orders.xml | cut -d : -f1'));
$totalLines = intval(shell_exec('wc -l orders.xml'));
echo shell_exec("sed -n '".$line.",".$totalLines."p' orders.xml");
```

Maybe you can just put 9999999999 instead of caculating the total lines. Not saying you should of course ;) ;)

I don't know if this is faster than just going through the file with XMLReader but I guess it's up to you to decide if it's worth it.

I hope this can give you further ideas to solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for giving some ideas what to do! :-)

Comment: @SimonThomsen How did you work this out at the end? I am very curious to see what you came up with. Thanks ;)