# XML SAX Parser with PHP7

Tags: php, xml, php-7, saxparser

I need to read an XML file from the top to the bottom, while doing my reseach I found out about SAX Parser, and more exaclty I found this link:

http://www.brainbell.com/tutorials/php/Parsing_XML_With_SAX.htm which works well and is exactly what I need.

But I can't find an exemple of SAX Parser with a PHP class or in a more "PHP7's way" , I was wondering if it was depreciate or it there are any better alternatives nowadays ?

Comment: Have a look at XMLReader (http://php.net/manual/en/book.xmlreader.php)

Comment: Initating the parser is done using `xml_parser_create` in the given example, and thats a function still present in PHP. Is that already fine for you or are you using something more specific?

Comment: It's fine I was just wondering if there are sometings better, I'm going to have a look at XMLReader

Answer (score 3):

XMLReader (http://php.net/manual/en/book.xmlreader.php) provides a much more modern approach to processing XML piece by piece.  Even the article you refer to has this at the end...

> PHP 5.1 comes with XMLReader included by default. This is a wrapper on
>   libxml2 and mimics the application programming interface (API) of the
>   C# component for reading XML, XmlTextReader. It is much faster than
>   SAX and just easier to use.

There are a few examples round about how to use XMLReader-
[How to use XMLReader in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835177/how-to-use-xmlreader-in-php)