# XMLReader get a node name

Tags: php, xml, xmlreader

I'm using XMLReader, how can I have in a while every node name?

```
$reader = new XMLReader;
$reader->xml($MyXml);
while ($reader->read() !== FALSE) {
  if ($reader->name === 'Product' && $reader->nodeType === XMLReader::ELEMENT) {    
    if ($reader->readString() != '') {
      echo $reader->getAttribute(name).'  -->  '.$reader->readString();                 
    }
  }
}
```

I need to have every node name this way don't work `echo $reader->getAttribute(name)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use XMLReader in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835177/how-to-use-xmlreader-in-php)

Comment: hello Mohammad
i saw a post u remind me  but i didnt found how to get node name, im not so expert with XMLReader (first time i use) do u know how can i have that attribute?

Comment: You can get node name in while using `$reader->name`

Answer (score 0):

Ouch i found a way in really simple solution... omg

[solution](http://codepad.org/1fNDWDba)

so simple way was in a while add a second $reader->read();

```
    while($reader->read())
{
        if($reader->nodeType == XMLREADER::ELEMENT)
        {
                $name = (string)$reader->name;
                $reader->read();
                $valu = (string)$reader->value;
                echo $name .' --> '.$valu . "\n";
        }
}
```