# Using XMLreader to read and parse large XML files. Empty values problem

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, xmlreader

I need to read XML files about 1 GB in size. My XML:

```
<products>
<product>
<categoryName>Kable i konwertery AV</categoryName>
<brandName>Belkin</brandName>
<productCode>AV10176bt1M-BLK</productCode>
<productId>5616488</productId>
<productFullName>Kabel Belkin Kabel HDMI Ultra HD High Speed 1m-AV10176bt1M-BLK</productFullName>
<productEan>0745883767465</productEan>
<productEuroPriceNetto>59.71</productEuroPriceNetto>
<productFrontendPriceNetto>258.54</productFrontendPriceNetto>
<productFastestSupplierQuantity>23</productFastestSupplierQuantity>
<deliveryEstimatedDays>2</deliveryEstimatedDays>
</product>
<product>
<categoryName>Telewizory</categoryName>
<brandName>Sony</brandName>
<productCode>KDL32WD757SAEP</productCode>
<productId>1005662</productId>
<productFullName>Telewizor Sony KDL-32WD757 SAEP</productFullName>
<productEan></productEan>
<productEuroPriceNetto>412.33</productEuroPriceNetto>
<productFrontendPriceNetto>1785.38</productFrontendPriceNetto>
<productFastestSupplierQuantity>11</productFastestSupplierQuantity>
<deliveryEstimatedDays>6</deliveryEstimatedDays>
</product>
<product>
<categoryName>Kuchnie i akcesoria</categoryName>
<brandName>Brimarex</brandName>
<productCode>1566287</productCode>
<productId>885156</productId>
<productFullName>Brimarex Drewniane owoce, Kiwi - 1566287</productFullName>
<productEan></productEan>
<productEuroPriceNetto>0.7</productEuroPriceNetto>
<productFrontendPriceNetto>3.05</productFrontendPriceNetto>
<productFastestSupplierQuantity>7</productFastestSupplierQuantity>
<deliveryEstimatedDays>3</deliveryEstimatedDays>
</product>
</products>
```

I use XML reader.

```
$reader = new XMLReader();
$reader->open($url);
$count = 0;

while($reader->read()) {
    if($reader->nodeType == XMLReader::ELEMENT)
        $nodeName = $reader->name;

    if(($reader->nodeType == XMLReader::TEXT || $reader->nodeType == XMLReader::CDATA)) {

        if ($nodeName == 'categoryName') $categoryName = $reader->value;
        if ($nodeName == 'brandName') $brandName = $reader->value;
        if ($nodeName == 'productCode') $productCode = $reader->value;
        if ($nodeName == 'productId') $productId = $reader->value;
        if ($nodeName == 'productFullName') $productFullName = $reader->value;
        if ($nodeName == 'productEan') $productEan = $reader->value;
        if ($nodeName == 'productEuroPriceNetto') $productEuroPriceNetto = $reader->value;
        if ($nodeName == 'productFastestSupplierQuantity') $productFastestSupplierQuantity = $reader->value;
        if ($nodeName == 'deliveryEstimatedDays') $deliveryEstimatedDays = $reader->value;
    }

    if($reader->nodeType == XMLReader::END_ELEMENT && $reader->name == 'product') {
        $count++;
    }
}
$reader->close();
```

All is working fine except one problem... When some value is missing, for example `<productEan></productEan>` in output I am getting a value from the previous, not empty tag till another tag which is not empty.

For example, if previous node is like in example `<productEan>0745883767465</productEan>` and another two `<productEan></productEan>` are empty in output array I getting same value, `0745883767465`.

What is the right way to solve this problem? Or maybe some one have working solution...

Comment: It may also be worth having a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835177/how-to-use-xmlreader-in-php which shows how to read in an entire product item which you can then process as a SimpleXML record ( so `$node->productEan`)

Comment: Code suggested by @Nick working fine with smallest xml. But with large XML, I getting out of memory error. So there are issue now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some code that will do what you want. It saves the value for each element when it encounters a `TEXT` or `CDATA` node, then stores it when it gets to `END_ELEMENT`. At that time the saved value is set to `''`, so that if no value is found for an element, it gets an empty string (this could be changed to `null` if you prefer). It also deals with self-closing tags for example `<brandName />` with an `isEmptyElement` check when a `ELEMENT` node is found. It takes advantage of PHPs variable variables to avoid the long sequence of `if ($nodename == ...)` that you have in your code, but also uses an array to store the values for each product, which longer term I think is a better solution for your problem.

```
$reader = new XMLReader();
$reader->xml($xml);
$count = 0;
$this_value = '';
$products = array();
while($reader->read()) {
    switch ($reader->nodeType) {
        case XMLReader::ELEMENT:
            // deal with self-closing tags e.g. <productEan />
            if ($reader->isEmptyElement) {
                ${$reader->name} = '';
                $products[$count][$reader->name] = '';
            }
            break;
        case XMLReader::TEXT:
        case XMLReader::CDATA:
            // save the value for storage when we get to the end of the element
            $this_value = $reader->value;
            break;
        case XMLReader::END_ELEMENT:
            if ($reader->name == 'product') {
                $count++;
                print_r(array($categoryName, $brandName, $productCode, $productId, $productFullName, $productEan, $productEuroPriceNetto, $productFrontendPriceNetto, $productFastestSupplierQuantity, $deliveryEstimatedDays));
            }
            elseif ($reader->name != 'products') {
                ${$reader->name} = $this_value;
                $products[$count][$reader->name] = $this_value;
                // set this_value to a blank string to allow for empty tags
                $this_value = '';
            }
            break;
        case XMLReader::WHITESPACE:
        case XMLReader::SIGNIFICANT_WHITESPACE:
        default:
            // nothing to do
            break;
    }
}
$reader->close();
print_r($products);
```

I've omitted the output as it's quite long but you can see the code in operation in this [demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/BIjM2).

Comment: worked fine some time and suddenly i get an error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in ... line `${$reader->name} = $this_value;`.  I have increased memory size in php.ini up to 2048M I tried set it in my current php file `ini_set('memory_limit','2048M');` But nothing help... Where the problem ?

Comment: @K.B. it sounds like your input data is too large so you will need to process the data inside the loop instead of storing it. So in the `if ($reader->name == 'product`)` block you should do all the processing of the data and then (if you are using an array), throw it away by setting `$products = array();`

Comment: Yes this XML up to 1 GB. In first try i have used `foreach($products as $product)` outside of your script. Then I have tried to move all stuff to `if ($reader->name == 'product)` block like you suggested, but it does not help, or maybe I miss something. On my local server script working, but on remote server does not work. I can give the link of this XML, maybe you can suggest solution for this issue...

Comment: When you used the `foreach` did it run out of memory in the `while ($reader->read)` loop or the `foreach` loop?

Comment: On this line `${$reader->name} = $this_value;` I getting out of memory error, when use foreach.

Comment: @K.B. so that is still within the reading loop. When you changed to process the data in the loop, did you also get rid of the `$products` array?

Comment: Thanks. I got it. working... `results of memory usage: Number of items=852229 memory_get_usage() =858.8671875kb memory_get_usage(true) =2048kb memory_get_peak_usage() =859.265625kb memory_get_peak_usage(true) =2048kb`.. reduced 100 times  Seems now no issues...

Comment: @K.B. glad to hear it. Processing that volume of data can definitely be tricky.

Comment: Storing the data to process is actually the last thing you want to do when reading a large file.  The whole point of processing it one at a time is that there may be so much data you run out of memory - that's why I suggested to process the data when you get to the end of the `<product>` element.

Comment: @NigelRen you are absolutely right. I should have paid more attention to that up front but I am used to working with much larger datasets and machines.

Answer (score 1):

If instead of using individual values, you store the values in an array of details, you can blank the array out once you have processed each element...

```
$reader->open($url);
$count = 0;

$data = [];
while($reader->read()) {
    if($reader->nodeType == XMLReader::ELEMENT)
        $nodeName = $reader->name;

        if(($reader->nodeType == XMLReader::TEXT || $reader->nodeType == XMLReader::CDATA)) {
            $data[$nodeName] = $reader->value;
        }

        if($reader->nodeType == XMLReader::END_ELEMENT && $reader->name == 'product') {
            // Process data
            echo ($data['productEan']??"Empty").PHP_EOL;
            // Reset
            $data = [];
            $count++;
        }
}
$reader->close();
```

which with your test data gives...

```
0745883767465
Empty
Empty
```

Answer (score 0):

Reset all variables on each loop. It seems that if you do not assign any value to it, it is getting the previous assigned value.

```
<?php 
while($reader->read()) {
    $categoryName = 
    $brandName = 
    $productCode = 
    $productId = 
    $productFullName = 
    $productEan = 
    $productEuroPriceNetto = 
    $productFastestSupplierQuantity = 
    $deliveryEstimatedDays = '';
//... code
}
?>
```

Comment: Idea is good to reset variables each loop but i'm stuck... How to do it?

Comment: It is on my answer, give an empty value to it just after open the while...

Comment: hmmm does not work, no output at all... maybe I'm tired and i need some rest :), but i'm here stuck at all