PHP DOMDocument memory usage explodes non-linearly with large XML files
I'm encountering severe memory scaling issues when using DOMDocument with XPath on large XML files in PHP 8.3. The memory usage appears to be non-linear:
$dom = new \DOMDocument();
$dom->load("SwissProt.xml");

To reproduce (this is a 115mb file):
wget "https://aiweb.cs.washington.edu/research/projects/xmltk/xmldata/data/SwissProt/SwissProt.xml"

If you have gnu time installed you can run it with
time -v php test.php

...
Maximum resident set size (kbytes): 1697648
...

Yup that's 1.6GB!
Observed memory usage:

80MB XML file → uses ~500MB memory
300MB XML file → uses several GB of memory

This non-linear memory scaling makes it impractical for larger files, is there some way I can still use DomDocument without having the entire document in memory? Streaming the file or something? I guess a work around is to split the actual XML file into multiple chunks.
There are alternatives but I need DomDocument as I need to query an element via an XPath.

This seems to be due the the underlying libxml2 library here is another post about it libxml2 taking huge memory(like 8GB for 600MB doc) for parsing
I encountered very similar memory consumption using python's lxml library as well.

If your XPath has some sort of local scope, you could load in chunks with XMLReader (some info on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835177/how-to-use-xmlreader-in-php)

XMLReader does not allow an XPath to be used though.

The example on the link shows how you can load segments of the XML into SimpleXML (and therefore DMDocument) which does.  So if the XPath is within certain nodes - you might be able to do it this way. If your XPath covers huge parts of the document though - it's not an option.

Why do you need XPath? I took a look at the XML and it doesn't seem very complex. You could certainly parse it with XMLReader.

The XML file linked is just an example to demonstrate the memory usage.
